# Debugging: IE6 + SSL + AJAX + post form = 404 error

Tags: ajax, debugging, internet-explorer, ssl, internet-explorer-6

**The Setting:**
The program in question tries to post form data via an AJAX call to a target procedure contained in the same package as the caller. This is done for a site that uses a secure connection (HTTPS). The technology used here is [PLSQL](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/PL/SQL_FAQ) and the [DOJO](http://dojotoolkit.org/) JavaScript library. The development tool is [basically a text editor](http://www.allroundautomations.nl/plsqldev.html).

**Code Snippet:**

```
> function testPost() {  
>>    dojo.xhrPost( {  
             url: ''dr_tm_w_0120.test_post'',  
             form: ''orgForm'',  
             load: testPostXHRCallback,  
             error: testPostXHRError  
            });  
      }  

> function testPostXHRCallback(data,ioArgs) {  
>>          alert(''post callback'');  
          try{  
          dojo.byId("messageDiv").innerHTML = data;  
          }  
          catch(ex){  
                if(ex.name == "TypeError")  
                {  
                  alert("A type error occurred.");  
                }  
          }   
          return data;  
       }         
> 
function testPostXHRError(data, ioArgs) {    
>>          alert(data);  
          alert(''Error when retrieving data from the server!'');  
          return data;  
       }
```

**The Problem:**
When using IE6 (which the entire user-base uses), the response sent back from the server is a 404 error.

**Observations:**
The program works fine in Firefox.
The calling procedure cannot target any procedures within the same package.
The calling procedure can target outside sites (both http, https).
The other AJAX calls in the package that are not posts of form data work fine.
I've searched the *internets* and consulted with senior-skilled team members and haven't discovered anything that satisfactorily addresses the issue.
*Tried [Q&A](http://dojotoolkit.org/forum/dojo-core-dojo-0-9/dojo-core-support/xhrpost-firefox-fine-ie-not-so-much) over at Dojo support forums.

**The Questions:**
What troubleshooting techniques do you recommend?
What troubleshooting tools do you recommend for HTTPS analyzing?
Any hypotheses on what the issue might be?
Any ideas for workarounds that aren't total (bad) hacks?

**Ed. The Solution**
lomaxx, thx for the [fiddler](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/PL/SQL_FAQ) tip. you have no idea how awesome it was to get that and use it as a debugging tool. after starting it up this is what i found and how i fixed it (at least in the short term):

```
> ef Fri, 8 Aug 2008 14:01:26 GMT dr_tm_w_0120.test_post: SIGNATURE (parameter names) MISMATCH VARIABLES IN FORM NOT IN PROCEDURE: SO1_DISPLAYED_,PO1_DISPLAYED_,RWA2_DISPLAYED_,DD1_DISPLAYED_ NON-DEFAULT VARIABLES IN PROCEDURE NOT IN FORM: 0
```

After seeing that message from the server, I kicked around Fiddler a bit more to see what else I could learn from it. Found that there's a WebForms tab that shows the values in the web form. Wouldn't you know it, the "`xxx_DISPLAYED_`" fields above were in it.

I don't really understand yet why these fields exist, because I didn't create them explicitly in the web `PLSQL` code. But I do understand now that the target procedure has to include them as parameters to work correctly. Again, this is only in the case of `IE6` for me, as Firefox worked fine.

Well, that the short term answer and hack to fix it. Hopefully, a little more work in this area will lead to a better understanding of the fundamentals going on here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First port of call would be to fire up [Fiddler](http://www.fiddlertool.com/fiddler/) and analyze the data going to and from the browser.

Take a look at the headers, the url actually being called and the params (if any) being passed to the AJAX method and see if it all looks good before getting to the server.

If that all looks ok, is there any way you can verify it's actually hitting the server via logging, or tracing in the AJAX method?

ed: another thing I would try is rig up a test page to call the AJAX method on the server using a non-ajax based call and analyze the traffic in fiddler and compare the two.

Comment: Lomaxx: *Fiddler is for HTTP. *Headers, url, params are all good *Have to contact our corporate admins and see if they're feeling nice enough to look at the logs

Comment: "Fiddler is for HTTP." Interesting... on the front page it says: "Fiddler 2 has replaced Fiddler 1.x.
**Fiddler 2 supports debugging HTTPS** traffic, a richer extensibility model, and can by installed side-by-side with Fiddler 1.x if desired. Note that Fiddler 2 requires version 2.0 of the .NET Framework." I still reckon it's worth firing it up :)