# Is there a way to include a fragment identifier when using Asp.Net MVC ActionLink, RedirectToAction, etc.?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I want some links to include a fragment identifier. Like some of the URLs on this site:

[Debugging: IE6 + SSL + AJAX + post form = 404 error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5619/ie6-ssl-ajax-post-form-404-error)**#5626**

Is there a way to do this with any of the built-in methods in MVC? Or would I have to roll my own HTML helpers?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We're looking at including support for this in our next release.

Comment: is this going to be targetting to be released in the dev10?

Answer (score 19):

As Brad Wilson wrote, you can build your own link in your views by simply concatenating strings. But to append a fragment name to a redirect generated via RedirectToAction (or similar) you'll need something like this:

```
public class RedirectToRouteResultEx : RedirectToRouteResult {

    public RedirectToRouteResultEx(RouteValueDictionary values)
        : base(values) {
    }

    public RedirectToRouteResultEx(string routeName, RouteValueDictionary values)
        : base(routeName, values) {
    }

    public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context) {
        var destination = new StringBuilder();

        var helper = new UrlHelper(context.RequestContext);
        destination.Append(helper.RouteUrl(RouteName, RouteValues));

        //Add href fragment if set
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Fragment)) {
            destination.AppendFormat("#{0}", Fragment);
        }

        context.HttpContext.Response.Redirect(destination.ToString(), false);
    }

    public string Fragment { get; set; }
}

public static class RedirectToRouteResultExtensions {
    public static RedirectToRouteResultEx AddFragment(this RedirectToRouteResult result, string fragment) {
        return new RedirectToRouteResultEx(result.RouteName, result.RouteValues) {
            Fragment = fragment
        };
    }
}
```

And then, in your controller, you'd call:

```
return RedirectToAction("MyAction", "MyController")
       .AddFragment("fragment-name");
```

That should generate the URL correctly.

Comment: This is great. In MVC3 there's an overload to `ActionLink` that lets you do a fragment, but not `RedirectToAction`.

Answer (score 4):

In MVC3 (and possibly earlier I haven't checked), you can use UrlHelper.GenerateUrl passing in the fragment parameter. Here's a helper method I use to wrap the functionalityL

```
public static string Action(this UrlHelper url, string actionName, string controllerName, string fragment, object routeValues)
{
    return UrlHelper.GenerateUrl(
        routeName: null,
        actionName: actionName,
        controllerName: controllerName,
        routeValues: new System.Web.Routing.RouteValueDictionary(routeValues),
        fragment: fragment,
        protocol: null,
        hostName: null,
        routeCollection: url.RouteCollection,
        requestContext: url.RequestContext,
        includeImplicitMvcValues: true /*helps fill in the nulls above*/
    );
}
```

Comment: A little awkward, but it's the best of the answers here. Maybe, the others are just out dated.

Answer (score 3):

@Dominic,

I'm almost positive that putting that in the route will cause routing issues.

@Ricky,

Until MVC has support for this, you can be a little more "old school" about how you make your routes. For example, you can convert:

```
<%= Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index") %>
```

into:

```
<a href='<%= Url.Action("Index") %>#2345'>Home</a>
```

Or you can write your own helper that does essentially the same thing.

Comment: I tried targets in routes with ASP.NET MVC Preview 3 and there was no problem with routing. So although you're "almost positive" it would be useful for you to elaborate on what issues there will be.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is: No. In ASP.NET MVC Preview 3 there's no first-class way for including an anchor in an action link. Unlike Rails' url_for :anchor, UrlHelper.GenerateUrl (and ActionLink, RedirectToAction and so on which use it) don't have a magic property name that lets you encode an anchor.

As you point out, you could roll your own that does. This is probably the cleanest solution.

Hackily, you could just include an anchor in a route and specify the value in your parameters hash:

```
routes.MapRoute("WithTarget", "{controller}/{action}/{id}#{target}");
...
<%= Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", new { target = "foo" })%>
```

This will generate a URL like /Home/Index/#foo. Unfortunately this doesn't play well with URL parameters, which appear at the end of the URL. So this hack is only workable in really simple circumstances where all of your parameters appear as URL path components.

Answer (score 0):

This is a client side solution but if you have jquery available you can do something like this.

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('div.imageHolder > a').each(function () {
            $(this).attr('href', $(this).attr('href') + '#tab-works');
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Fragment identifiers are supported in MVC 5. See `ActionLink`'s overloads at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460522(v=vs.118).aspx and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492938(v=vs.118).aspx.